# How to increase the width of the Eclipse editor?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm coding in eclipse. I format my code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, but the width of editor isn't great enough. How can I increase the width?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming this means you want to increase the maximum line width, you want to go into Preferences (Window -> Preferences) then find the Java -> Code Style -> Formatter menu. (Just type "formatter" into the search box and you'll find it quickly.)

[image: Preferences dialog]

Click "Edit" for your active profile, then go to the Line Wrapping tab. The first item should be "Maximum line width". Set the value to some appropriate limit (e.g. 120) and reformat.

[image: Line Wrapping preferences]